# How to check this on wio.db

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a rank command and using wio.db but l cant fetch all data in wio.db can someone look? (my wio.db version: 4.0.9)

error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined`

code:

```js
let herkes = client.db.all().filter(i => i.ID.startsWith("xp_")).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
let seviye = herkes.map(x => x.ID).indexOf(xp_${message.author.id}) + 1;
```

Comment: Where is client defined?

Comment: It means `client.db` is undefined. Where is `client` coming from? Can you update your question with more details?

Comment: yes client defined

Comment: can you try this? on 4.0.9 version of wio.db